# JPA Manual Transaction Retry on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, transactions

I have been trying to implement manual transaction retry with JPA on GAE with no luck..it never throws an exception...I have the same code working using the low level API and it works fine...but that said I want to get away from using the low level API. Anyone know of how to manually retry transactions using JPA on GAE? The problem I am having is that it never throws a CuncurrentModificationException or any exception for that matter when two people are updating the same entity group.

Any one try this out before? I have seen JDO examples and Low Level API examples out there but nothing on JPA.

Thanks!
Jeff